# How to get last record in spring mongo?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have a transaction class which stores the each transaction of a customer,Following are the fields in this class.

```
class Transaction{
    @Id
    private String id;
    private Date date;
    private String customerId;
    private double openBalance;
    private double transctionAmount;
    private double finalAmount;

}
```

I need to fetch only the last inserted record of a customer (let say for customerId = cust123).

I defined following function in repository.

```
public interface TranscationRepository extends MongoRepository<Transaction, String> {
    Optional<Transaction> findTopByCustomerIdOrderByIdDesc(String id);
}
```

This method giving last entry not by customerId but overall. I tried few modifications to it but did not get success.

I know I can findAllByCustomer but I don't want to pull huge list of transaction which is of no use in this use case. What is correct signature in spring mongo to get last inserted record by a field? I am ok to use custom @Query also.
Thank you.

Comment: Why you need `Top` when you filter by `Id`?